# Animation block appearance bottom-top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want something like that but with animation from bottom to top. It must be atop image and take full page. How can I do it?

```js
function viewDiv() {
    document.getElementById("text").classList.add("my-class");
}
```

```css
.content-blocker {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   z-index: 4444;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

.my-class {   
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;       
}
```

```html
<body>
   <input type="button" value="Click" onmousedown="viewDiv()">
   тут контент страницы
   <img src = "https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png">
   <div class="content-blocker" id = "text"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can make it to animate from top to bottom;

```js
function viewDiv(){
  document.getElementById("text").classList.add("my-class");;
}
```

```css
.content-blocker {
 visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        z-index: 4444;

    }
  .my-class {   visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1; 
    animation-name: dth;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
  
  }

@keyframes dth {
    from {height: 0;}
    to {height: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click" onmousedown="viewDiv()">
тут контент страницы
<img src = "https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png">
<div class="content-blocker" id = "text"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thats not what i catually mean, but its a good way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `width: 100%` and `height: 100vh` to take full screen for image, and `transform: translateY(-value)` to get animation from bottom to top. Here is the [Codepen sample](https://codepen.io/KaungKZ/pen/PoGLoeG)